# Sql Service broker BEGIN DIALOG CONVERSATION and SEND. Should they be in a transaction?

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I regularly see code that looks like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
BEGIN DIALOG CONVERSATION @u....
SEND ...
COMMIT;
```

BOL for BEGIN DIALOG doesn't use the transaction handling in the examples and it doesn't mention transactions at all.

Are transactions needed?  If so why?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the [BEGIN DIALOG CONVERSATION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187377.aspx) does not specify using a TRANSACTION for starting a Service Broker dialog. But many developers use them as a standard practice.

For example, the 2008 R2 TechNet page [Beginning a Conversation and Transmitting Messages](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb839493(v=sql.105).aspx) seems to recommend `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT TRANSACTION` (or `ROLLBACK`) as a good practice.

This topic [Configuring Service Broker for Asynchronous Processing](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/03/sql-performance/configuring-service-broker) also shows transactions being used.

These multi-step examples that use transactions do so for the same reason transactions are used in other code.  Namely to ensure either a complete transaction or else a rollback to a consistent state.

Of course, you can decide if your Service Broker dialog is simple enough that you do not need a transaction. But that is up to you to decide.

Comment: Are you really saying this is an option?  Nothing bad happens because a transaction isn't used?  I don't know the internals of BEGIN DIALOG and SEND and how that interacts with a RECEIVE that is in a  transaction.  Is there a potential for blocking on system tables.  i have seen this wait_type and wonder if it can be caused by not using a transaction on the BEGIN/SEND.  SERVICE_BROKER_TRANSMISSION_WORKTABLE

Comment: @danholmes Along with your question in the previous comment, I am curious as to the consequence of _not_ using a transaction. Meaning, can some info be added to this answer related to what happens if, with no `BEGIN TRAN`, the `BEGIN DIALOG CONVERSATION` succeeds but the `SEND` fails for some reason. Is something left in a bad state in the Service Broker queue tables?

Comment: @danholmes - No, I would use a transaction.  Just saying that it "works" without a transaction, if that is what you want.